# Single Screen Payment

Tags: commerce

what I'm trying to do is create a "Upgrade account" screen where the user will chose a different level of upgrade.  Then they enter payment info and if all goes well the upgrade is processed.

Being new to Drupal there seem to be many options from the powerful [Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce) module to other more specific modules.  I was trying to go down the route mentioned here: https://commerceguys.com/blog/creating-orders-drupal-commerce-api

However, I'm not even sure how to execute that PHP from the click of a button.

So my questions really are:

- Is the [Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce) module the right fit (based on what I've mentioned)?
- If so, how would I go about connecting the dots from building a screen to calling the PHP to kickoff the checkout?